# Need help identifying this flower

Tags: identification, flowers

I have this wild flower growing in my yard. It's Approximately 4-5 feet tall, northern Indiana

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is *Helianthus strumosus*, or Paleleaf woodland sunflower. It is from the *Astraceae* (Aster) [family](https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=hest). It is a relative of the common sunflower. This plant is native to US and Canada.